# how to use express post method with google Oauth2.0 during authorized redirection URL

Tags: rest, express, oauth-2.0

I am a person who is practicing Google oauth2.0. I am creating an example, but it does not work well with Oauth authentication.

First, the operation in index.html is as follows. Request a Oauth "request token" with a simple  tag using the href command.

```
<a href="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcalendar.readonly&access_type=offline&
include_granted_scopes=true&state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2FreceiveCode&response_type=code&client_id=665922514832-f7n0s3chgn41vsojtg4gfl2j7c5a5lfr.apps.googleusercontent.com">Using google API
</a>
<form action='http://localhost:3000/user' method='get'>
    <button name="subject" type="submit" value='THIS 123!@# IS GET!!' href='www.google.com'>get</button>
</form>
```

The authorized redirect URI here is http: // localhost: 3000 / receiveCode.

I wanted to use the restful API instead of using the php file.

It worked so well up to here. The problem is that I can not use the Scope after login to Google site.
According to Step 5 of the Google reference https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer,

a session is linked to an Authorized redirect URI and then various data such as Code values ​​are sent to POST to request an Access Token

However, in receiveCode that I set as router, it is always GET.

The code looks like this and result URL:

http://localhost:3000/receiveCode?state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&code=4/AAAhDsl2wLidOA1Gqq9UzXbeWMe25sYx_8HtXx3_rGgeY9cm5mp2uSvdRBNqF6Da9ScEp0jE10mF_ibibEsM3x4&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly#

```
router.get('/receiveCode', (req, res, next) => {
    //NOT ERROR BUT NOT POST
})

router.post('/receiveCode', (req, res, next) => {
    // ERROR (Internal Server Error)
    // actually... never calling enter post method
})
```

I am not sure whether this is a structural problem or an API that uses post.

Should not you use restAPI in express in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resources identified by the `redirect_uri` should indeed be retrieved via the HTTP `GET` method, so I think so far everything is working for you as intended.

From here, you should be able to retrieve the query parameters you need to handle your `/receiveCode` implementation from the express `req` variable `params` [property](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params), e.g.:

```
req.params.code
```

## Explanation

How do we know `GET` is correct?

The Google docs are not very clear until you look at the implementation example:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#example

If you take a look at e.g. the Ruby example there (excerpted below), you can see that the callback `/oauth2callback` is analogous to your `/receiveCode` and is indeed implemented with GET:

> ```
> require 'google/apis/drive_v2'
> require 'google/api_client/client_secrets'
> require 'json'
> require 'sinatra'
>
> enable :sessions
> set :session_secret, 'setme'
>
> get '/' do
>   unless session.has_key?(:credentials)
>     redirect to('/oauth2callback')
>   end
>   client_opts = JSON.parse(session[:credentials])
>   auth_client = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(client_opts)
>   drive = Google::Apis::DriveV2::DriveService.new
>   files = drive.list_files(options: { authorization: auth_client })
>   "<pre>#{JSON.pretty_generate(files.to_h)}</pre>"
> end
>
> get '/oauth2callback' do
>   client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load
>   auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
>   auth_client.update!(
>     :scope => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
>     :redirect_uri => url('/oauth2callback'))
>   if request['code'] == nil
>     auth_uri = auth_client.authorization_uri.to_s
>     redirect to(auth_uri)
>   else
>     auth_client.code = request['code']
>     auth_client.fetch_access_token!
>     auth_client.client_secret = nil
>     session[:credentials] = auth_client.to_json
>     redirect to('/')
>   end
> end
> ```

For some additional context, here are the corresponding parts of the Oauth 2 spec:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.2

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.1

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2

Comment: Thanks. But there is one question. In the linked example, I get a GET, send it to post, and redirect it again. Is this a good structure?

Comment: That sounds right. You can see this part better in the HTTP/REST example at https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#example (rather than Ruby which abstracts it away in a library). Have a look at the part near `r = requests.post('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token', data=data)
` for the POST to token endpoint step, which happens after you receive the GET `/receiveCode`.